# Spring Boot + Scheduling Multiple Spring Batch Jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch, batch-processing

Guys I followed the below link to create a spring batch job and schedule it. But this approach fails when i create multiple jobs. Has anyone tried a different approach to create multiple Spring batch jobs and schedule them  ?

[Spring boot with Spring batch and Scheduler](http://www.kswaughs.com/2016/03/spring-boot-batch-job-scheduler-example.html?showComment=1505637361925#c4526275719086854553)

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? Provide your non-working example maybe?

Comment: Could you provide any stack-trace or error message to see where the application fails?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. I resolved the issues.